# Limit of an integral of a periodic function

Tags: integration, limits

I have to calculate this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^n \frac{dx}{5+4\cos(x)}$$

But I can't seem to simplify the integral, so I tried just calculating some values for $\frac {dx}{5+4\cos(x)}$, but this function is periodic with some peaks when $4cos(x)=0$. 
Could someone show me just how to start simplifying the integral (and maybe what to do after)?

Comment: you can evaluate the integral in terms of $n$ using the substitution $t=\tan(\frac x2)$ and then consider the limit.

Comment: Decompose the range as $[0,p]\cup[p,n]$, where $p=2\pi\lfloor n/2\pi\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}=\frac{2\pi}{3}
$$
Using residue theorem. Let $z=e^{ix}$, then $dz=ie^{ix}dx=izdx$. Thus
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}&=\int_C\frac{1}{5+4\left(\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}\right)}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=\int_C \frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{2z^2+5z+2}dz\\
&=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(f;-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{3i}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3},
\end{align}
where $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$, and $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{i(2z^2+5z+2)}$.

For all $n$, there is $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2p \pi < n < 2(p+1)\pi$, and
$$
\frac{2p \pi}{3} = \int_0^{2p \pi} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}\le \int_0^{n} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x} \le \int_0^{2(p+1) \pi} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x} =\frac{2(p+1)\pi}{3}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{2p \pi}{3n} \le \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}\le \frac{2(p+1)\pi}{3n}
$$
Now we will find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p}{n}$. From $2p \pi < n < 2(p+1)\pi$, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(1-\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) < \frac{p}{n} < \frac{1}{2\pi}
$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p}{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ by squeeze theorem. Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2p \pi}{3n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(p+1)\pi}{3n}=\frac{1}{3},
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n} \frac{dx}{5+4\cos x}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
By squeeze theorem.

Comment: how did you observe that for $n=2/_pi% the integral has that value or that it has significant importance for solving the problem?

Comment: @FelixMada Just because I learned complex analysis, especially computing definite integral of function(trigonometric function included) such as $\frac{1}{2+\cos x}$, $\frac{1}{1+\sin^2 x}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ using residue theorem. Also, I'm not familiar with trigonometric substitution. However, if $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $2k\pi$ is not an integer, so I had to apply squeeze theorem to remove the gap.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

With $z=e^{ix}$, the integral becomes

$$\int \frac1{5+2z+2z^{-1}}\frac{dz}{iz}=-i\int\frac{dz}{2z^2+5z+2}=-i\int\left(\frac2{6z+3}-\frac1{3z+6}\right)dz\\
=-i\ln\left(\frac{6z+3}{6z+12}\right).$$